# How to add info from userform into 2 columns , looking for the first empty row in each

Tags: excel, userform

Looks very easy , but I can still not figure out why everyting gets added to column A, and why not to column "AN" as I have defined iRowB

Many thanks for the help

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRowA As Long
Dim iRowB As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Results draft")

'find first empty row in database

iRowA = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

iRowB = ws.Range("AN:AN").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1


If Trim(Me.HomeTeam.Value) = "" Then
Me.HomeTeam.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please insert the result"
Exit Sub
End If


With ws

.Cells(iRowA, 1).Value = Me.HomeTeam.Value


.Cells(iRowB, 1).Value = Me.Goal1.Value



End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just create two separate `iRow` values? `iRowA` and `iRowB`. You already have `iRowA` with this code: `iRow = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1` so just change `A:A` to `B:B` for `iRowB`? If this isn't what you're trying to do, you could explain a bit better what you're up to.

Comment: its somehow not working if I do it as above. Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Ok, got it , .Cells(iRowB, 1).Value = Me.Goal1.Value  - 1 to be modified to "AN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .Cells(iRow, 1), the iRow is the row number, and the 1 is the column number.  1 is column A, 2 is column B, etc. So if you want the Goal to be in column B...

```
.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.Goal1.Value
```

Alternately, instead of the column number, you can put the column letter:

```
.Cells(iRow, "B").Value = Me.Goal1.Value
```

Comment: but iRow is defined as = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1 so the first empty row in column A. if I say (iRow;B) that is not going to mean the first emty row in column B

Comment: Why would you want corresponding data on different rows?